# Issue with getting folders on O365 server with Webklex\IMAP

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my Weblex Imap for Laravel plugin

I got my default account setup and finally got it connecting. I now have this small bit of code in a command:

```
    $oClient = Client::account('default');
    $oClient->connect();

    dd($oClient);

    $aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolderByName('inbox');
    dd($aAvailableFolders);
```

So, the client part works and when I dump oClient I get this, as expected:

```
    Webklex\IMAP\Client^ {#24
      +connection: imap resource @508
      +host: "outlook.office365.com"
      +port: 993
      +protocol: "imap"
      +encryption: "ssl"
      +validate_cert: true
      +username: redacted
      +password: redacted
      #read_only: false
      #active_folder: false
      #connected: true
      #errors: []
      #valid_config_keys: array:7 [
        0 => "host"
        1 => "port"
        2 => "encryption"
        3 => "validate_cert"
        4 => "username"
        5 => "password"
        6 => "protocol"
      ]
      #default_message_mask: "Webklex\IMAP\Support\Masks\AttachmentMask"
      #default_attachment_mask: "Webklex\IMAP\Support\Masks\AttachmentMask"
    }
```

The problem is, that second dump statement where I'm just trying to make sure it's getting the folders is failing. I originally had it looped as in the documentation and got the error so I threw in the dump/die statement to debug but on that line I get:

`Call to undefined method Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolderByName()`

Even if I try just `getFolders()` then I get an exception trace for `Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolders("Contacts/%")`

Comment: which client library and version are you using?? `Webklex/laravel-imap` or `Webklex/php-imap` or some other library?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's laravel-imap

Comment: which version of the package are you using?

Comment: Looks like 1.4.5

Comment: The only way I've gotten it to work @Haridarshan is to use ```$aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolders(false);```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has dropped support for IMAP in Azure and 365.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: could you provide the source of this info?